# The getter 'AuthStateChanges' isn't defined for the type 'FirebaseAuth'

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to get UserProvider for Firebase Auth but the error says:

> The getter 'AuthStateChanges' isn't defined for the type 'FirebaseAuth'.

and

> Undefined name '_onStateChanged'.

```
UserProvider.initialize() : _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance {
_auth.AuthStateChanges.listen(_onStateChanged);}
```

Comment: auth state changes ref - https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage/#authentication-state. Check whether you have the method `_onStateChanged` where you could perform actions by checking the user's state.

Comment: The spelling is slightly off in your code. It should be `authStateChanges` starting with a lowercase `a`. See https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/authStateChanges.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/migration

DEPRECATED: onAuthStateChanged has been deprecated in favor of authStateChanges().

Answer (score 0):

Use authStateChanges() in favor of authStateChanges()

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).